# Kiel esprimi "food intolerance" en Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, medicine

Kiel oni esprimu en Esperanto tion, kion en la angla oni nomiĝas "food intolerance" (vidu ĉe [Vikipedio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_intolerance)) kaj en la germana "Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeit" (vidu ĉe [Vikipedio](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahrungsmittelunvertr%C3%A4glichkeit)), t.e., la cirkonstancon, ke iuj malsaniĝus aŭ eĉ mortus, se ili trinkus aŭ manĝus ion certan (en kvanto, kio estus tute normala kaj ne malsaniga al aliaj)?

Estas ege facile ĉirkaŭskribi la fakton, ke iu havas ian specifan "food intolerance", per "Ri ne povas trinki / manĝi *<la certan manĝaĵon aŭ trinkaĵon>*.", sed kelkfoje oni volas substantivon por la kondiĉo mem.

Laŭvorta traduko de "intolerance" gvidas al **"maltoleremo"**, sed ĉu ne tiu esprimo signifus, ke la persono (vole aŭ ideologie) kontraŭstaras la manĝaĵon aŭ trinkaĵon? "toleri" laŭ ReVo ja havas ankaŭ la duan signifon "elteni, elporti, **ne ricevi difekton** de maloportuna kondiĉo", sed por tiuj sen la certa "food intolerance", la manĝaĵo aŭ trinkaĵo ja tute ne estas nepre maloportuna, kaj "maltoleremo" estas tiel ofte uzata en la politika / ideologia signifo, ke mi timas, ke oni miskomprenus ĝin, se mi uzus ĝin por "food intolerance".

La *Kleines Wörterbuch Deutsch-Esperanto, Esperanto-Deutsch* de Ulrich Mathias kaj Dietrich Michael Weidmann listigas por "verträglich" en la senco de "verdaulich" la vorton **"digestebla"**. Tio ŝajnas iome pli taŭga, sed ne tute, ĉar ja ne ĉiu "Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeit" temas pri la eblecon / kapablon digesti la trinkaĵon aŭ manĝaĵon. (Kelkaj malbonaj efektoj okazas nur post la digesto, kiam substancoj ekz. eniras la sangon aŭ per la sango atingas certajn organojn.)

Ĉu ekzistas pli taŭga vorto aŭ esprimo por "food intolerance" / "Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeit"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tolereco` estas laŭ [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#tolereco_kd): *Grado, laŭ kiu organismo aŭ substanco toleras difinitan substancon*.

Oni povas do uzi tion kiel bazon. Ekzemple, oni listigas jenan vorton en PIV:

`netolerateco` - *Eco de nutraĵo aŭ de medikamento, ne tolerata de organismo*

kaj ekzemplon:

```
 netolerateco de la bovina lakto ĉe iu infano.
```

La ĝenerala formo povus esti `nutraĵa netolerateco` sed laŭ la kunteksto aŭ la bezono precizigi ankaŭ taŭgus, ekzemple, *ĥemia netolerateco*, *kuracila netolerateco*,...

Comment: Ha, jes, "-ec·" anstataŭ "-em·". Dankon!

Comment: Reta-vortaro eĉ donas [**netolero**](https://reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-2d.html#toler.0i)

Comment: @JoopEggen ankaŭ simpla `netolero de` bonas, sed ĝi estas ago dum `netolereco` estas kvalito. Do, kunteksto diktos kiu pli taŭgas (la `-atec-` formon mi sentas nebezonate peza). Interesa afero: en la frazoj en Reta-vortaro, la netoleratan objekton oni enkondukas per `je` sed oni devus uzi `de` (PMEG [klarigas tion](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/de/aga_o-vorto.html#i-tml)). La skribintoj verŝajne celis kvaliton (kie oni uzas kelkfoje `je`) sed uzis agan vorton (kie oni kutime uzas `de`).

Comment: Notu, ke dum la fruaj jaroj oni uzis akuzativon rekte post la substantivo por montri objekton. Do la ekzemplon en ReVo oni povas skribi ankaŭ per (jen kun -eco): ĉi tiu infano suferas netolereco**n** de laktaĵoj. Ial tiu stilo ne plu estas populara.